# My game plays itself?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been making a canvas game in HTML5 and am new to a lot of it. I would like to use solely javascript to create my elements too (it is easier to embed into other sites this way and I feel it is cleaner). I had my game reloading in order to play again, but I want to be able to keep track of the score and multiple other variables without having to put each into the URL (which I have been doing) to make it seem like the game is still going. I'm also going to add "power ups" and other things that need to be "remembered" by the script.

Anyways, here's my question. When one player kills another, the game will play itself for a while and make my computer very slow until I reload the page. Why is it doing this? I cleared the interval for the main function (which loops the game and keeps everything running) and this used to make everything stop moving - it no longer does. What's wrong here?

This is my game: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11168436/game/game.html

Controls: Move the skier with arrow keys and shoot with M (you shoot in the direction you were last moving in). The snowboarder is moved with ESDF and shoots with Q.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Ok heres what was basically happening, the variable interval existed in different scopes. So you were attempting to clear an interval.. but it wasn't the correct scope, so the var `interval` was really never being cleared (also you were using the incorrect syntax for clearing an interval).

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGQDr/1/)**

You should learn more about [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). You had `var interval` in a few different spots, one global and one locally in a function. This creates two seperate variables named interval. Heres a quick example,

```
var a = 10;
function(){
    var a = 1;
    console.log(a);
   // a will equal 1

}

console.log(a);
// a will equal 10
```

Anyway what I did to fix it was declared a global variable for `interval` and that variable is the only one used now for clearing ect.

Next issue I saw is you were using

`interval = window.clearInterval(interval)`

you only need to call

`window.clearInterval(interval)`

Its a good first attempt just keep learning :). Hopefully you understand what I did in the working example. Just compare it to your code, theres only a few minor differences all related to the scope of your variable `interval`

Answer (score 0):

These line may be the culprit:

`var interval = window.setInterval(main, 1);`

Bring that interval up to say, `30`, and your problem should go away.

Comment: No luck. Everything whizzed around like before.

Comment: @sc8ing Dang. Check for recursive function calls.

Comment: What are recursive function calls?

Comment: @sc8ing functions that call themselves. For example: `function f(){f();}`

Comment: Okay. Well, in my playAgain() function it sets a timeout for itself with a time of 1000 milliseconds, but then passes a variable to itself making sure to not call itself again. I'm not sure this would cause the "playing itself" though, since the time is for a whole second.

Comment: @sc8ing Hmm. I wouldn't know what else to check. As long as only one `timeout` is running, the code should work. Best of luck!